# Safe Navigation of indexed objects

Tags: c#, operators, roslyn, c#-6.0

With the introduction of Roslyn, C# gets the benefit of the Safe Navigation operator.
This is brilliant for objects that use dot notations e.g.

```
MyClass myClass = null;
var singleElement = myClass?.ArrayOfStrings[0];
```

In this instance myClass is null but the safe operator saves me from the exception.

My question is if you have an indexed object is there an equivalent implementation of the safe navigation operator? An example of needing this would look like this:

```
var myClass2 = new MyClass { ArrayOfStrings = null };
var singleElement2 = myClass2?.ArrayOfStrings[0];
```

In this instance myClass2 is not null but the ArrayOfStrings property is, so when I try and access it it will throw an exception. Because there is no dot notation between ArrayOfStrings and the index I can't add the safe nav operator.

Because this is an array I can use the safe nav operator in the following way, but this doesn't work for other collections such as Lists and DataRows

```
var myClass3 = new MyClass { ArrayOfStrings = null };
var singleElement3 = myClass3?.ArrayOfStrings?.GetValue(0);
```

Comment: Just to add, the term `Safe Navigation` is bit misleading, Since the operator only saves from `null` object. Hence the name [Null propagation operator](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status&referringTitle=Documentation). This will not save in case of `IndexOutOfRangeException` like `MyClass myClass = new MyClass { ArrayOfStrings = new string[2] }; var singleElement = myClass?.ArrayOfStrings?[5];`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the [Language Feature Status Page](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status&referringTitle=Documentation) it looks like you want:

```
var singleElement2 = myClass2?.ArrayOfStrings?[0];
```

The example on the page is:

```
customer?.Orders?[5]?.$price
```

... admittedly the `$price` part has been withdrawn now, I believe, but I would expect the indexed null propagation to work.